# How to Add Tags to work Items from within Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

As yo know Team Foundation 2013 has introduced Tags feature and I have been able to work with it using the web interface of the Team Project. but I was not able to access and set tags for work Items from within Visual Studio 2013. I just can add the Tags column to the query columns.

Is there a way to specify Tags and filter based on them for Work Items from within Visual Studio just like how it works in the web version of TFS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a work item tag within Visual Studio 2013 IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088167/how-to-add-a-work-item-tag-within-visual-studio-2013-ide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use tags in queries and filer data you need the  Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RTM installed on premise.

> With this release, tagging gets even better. View and edit tags right from Visual Studio, or use them as part of a work item query for both the Contains and Does Not Contains operators (in both Visual Studio and Web Access).

More details can be found here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-apr-2-vs

Comment: I can see how to filter with contains(which is way worse than how it works from web interface) and stuff, but how to set the Tags for the Work Item within VS?

Comment: Seems to me that you might have an older version of the TFS server installed on-premise. You should contact your TFS administrator to see if an upgrade to the version I mentioned earlier is possible. Keep in mind that I am talking about upgrading the TFS server (not the client which is what is installed on your local machine)

Comment: Our TFS Server is 2013, that's why I am able to set Tags for Work Items through Web interface, but cannot find the place to do that in Visual Studio!

Answer (score 3):

Aram,

Both Visual Studio **AND** TFS should be upgraded to "Update 2".

After you upgrade both, "Tags" should be available in work items also in Visual Studio.