# How to add a work item tag within Visual Studio 2013 IDE?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3) with git & Visual Studio Online as Source Control.
I can add tags to work items in the Visual Studio Online web experience but unable to do so in the Visual Studio 2013 IDE.

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding and editing tags in [Visual Studio 2013 has been enabled in Update 2](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-apr-2-vs.aspx). I'm currently running Visual Studio 2013 [Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921) and the functionality is available there.

[image: Adding a work item tag]

Make sure you [download and install the latest version of Visual Studio 2013 to get access to the latest goods](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2829760).

Comment: Or even better, in VS 2013 go to TOOLS->Extensions and Updates, choose Updates and then select the VS updates to install.

Comment: Installed Update 4 and there it is.