# assign tags to work items in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

Please click link to see picture since I am new user.

Thank you for understanding

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Mv5.png

My Question is 
    when I create new task, I could not found where is tags , any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a work item tag within Visual Studio 2013 IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088167/how-to-add-a-work-item-tag-within-visual-studio-2013-ide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tagging has been a web-only feature since TFS 2012 Update 2 (do you have this TFS version or higher?). We have [added tagging support to Visual Studio client](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-apr-2-vs.aspx) in 2013 Update 2. So it might be possible that you have a VS Client that doesn't support tagging yet.

You can always open the work item in the web to add tags or download a more recent version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my VS to update 4 and then tags show up

Answer (score 0):

Well, it has been there all the time, please see below screenshot.

[Add tag in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idcCG.png)

[Add tag in Web Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fyhe.png)

Please make sure you have enough permissions in TFS.  Such as
**Create tag definition** - - Can add tags through a work item form.

Comment: If you don't have permissions to create a tag definition, then you will still be able to see them. You only miss the "Add tag" button.